# Connect Activate and Deactivate Events to ALL Explorers in Outlook

Tags: vba, event-handling, outlook-2007

I have some activate/deactivate methods

```
Private Sub myOlExp_Activate()
'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub myOlExp_Deactivate()
End Sub
```

which are connected to the Explorer Object via

```
Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer (called in the "Application_Startup" method)
```

However, when I open an email or event or something else, it seems the ActiveExplorer changes and so the deactivate event is called.

I would like to tie the activate/deactivate events to ALL explorers Outlook can have, so that the activate/deactivate methods ONLY are called when I switch applications to/from Outlook. In other words, call the method when I switch to Outlook from Excel, then not call the Deactivate Event while opening emails, scheduling meetings, etc until I switch back to Excel.

```
Application.Explorers
```

seems to only return open explorers (and so when I open items/etc new ones are seemingly created). It may be possible to get this to work but I have not figured it out.

Essentially, I want an "outlook.activate" and "outlook.deactivate" method which is independent of what Outlook item/window I am viewing.

Comment: Is this the problem I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396080/outlook-vba-onactivate-method#comment15025724_11396080)?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, there is no way in VBA how to capture an event for all Explorers.

To work around this, you can handle Explorers_NewExplorer event to track new Explorers.

```
Dim WithEvents exps As Outlook.Explorers
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set exps = Application.Explorers
    Set exp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub
Private Sub exps_NewExplorer(ByVal Explorer As Explorer)
    Set exp = Explorer
End Sub
```

The main problem now, is to track activations. As you only have one object that is bound to events, we need to find a way how to assign the object to the newly active explorer.
Unfortunately, natural attempt below, does not work:

```
Private Sub exp_Deactivate()
    Debug.Print ("Win: " & Application.ActiveWindow.Caption & ", Expl: " & Application.ActiveExplorer.Caption)
    If Application.ActiveWindow.Class = olExplorer Then
         Set exp = Application.ActiveWindow   ' Caveat: This does not work!
    End If
End Sub
```

as Explorer_Deactivate event is fired BEFORE the switch is effective, that is Application.ActiveWindow and Application.ActiveExplorer both point to the explorer being deactivated, thus making it impossible to detect which Explorer was activated. And we need to know that, as we need to assign exp to the activated one.

If you have a fixed number of explorers (which in practice you always have), you can work around this limitation (i'd consider it rather as a design defect) by declaring variable
for each possible explorer and use ugly switch, e.g. something like:

```
Private Sub exp1_Aactivate()
    ... call your sub here ...
End Sub
Private Sub exp2_Activate()
    ... call your sub here ...
End Sub

Private Sub exps_NewExplorer(ByVal Explorer As Explorer)
    Select Case Application.Explorers.Count
        Case 1
            Set expl1 = Explorer
        Case 2
            Set expl2 = Explorer
        ... etc ...
```

Unfortunately i didnt yet find a way how to detect a new active explorer in any event fired from the old explorer. 
One possible (but still ugly) way might be if you could fire a timer and after couple of ms ActiveWindow might be already switched.